# How can I combine the desired rows together in R

Tags: r, rows

For example, now I have:

```
A 1 1 1 1 3 4
B 1 8 9 7 9 6
A 2 3 4 5 6 6
C 1 1 1 1 1 1.
```

I want to get the rows with same letter `A` together, like this:

```
A 1 1 1 1 3 4
A 2 3 4 5 6 6
```

What should I do? It's in R programming.

the letters in front of every row is not the name of row, just the first element in each row

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of your data (for instance, are A, B, A, C a column or row names?). If you're trying to sort your data by the letter, you should check out the `order` function.

Comment: `df[df[, 1] == "A", ]`, if `df` is your data set

Comment: @josilber, I doubt they are row names, as duplicate row names are not allowed.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `mat <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2) ; rownames(mat) <- c("A", "A")` does not generate an error, so it is possible. Either way, best if the OP posts a reproducible example.

Comment: @josilber, this is interesting, as it will generate an error if `mat` is a `data.frame`

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the letters in front of every row is not the name of row, just the first element in each row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order()` function to do that:

```
# reading the data
df <- read.table(header=FALSE, text="A 1 1 1 1 3 4
B 1 8 9 7 9 6
A 2 3 4 5 6 6
C 1 1 1 1 1 1")

# ordering the data according to the values in the first colum
df[order(df[,1]),]
```

Comment: thank you, but it shows" error in df[,1], object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: I should have named the dataframe `df` instead of `dat`; see my updated answer. It should work now.